# How to mock vrf random number in foundry/solidity

Tags: solidity, foundry, chainlink-vrf

My smart contract is basically like a casino with a coinflip game. 50% of the time, you double your money, the other 50% you lose your bet and the contract keeps it. I've managed to unit test the other components but I am struggling to test the house winning and the players winning separately as I can't figure out how to get the fulfillRandomWordsWithOverride() to work. This method should allow me to pass the random words I want to the fulFillRandomWords function in my contract to be called with. This would allow me to ensure that the house wins or vice versa. This method can be found in the mock file : https://github.com/smartcontractkit/chainlink-brownie-contracts/blob/c6d0ca512f1b09d93bc81415d246dbee7e5c6894/contracts/src/v0.8/mocks/VRFCoordinatorV2Mock.sol
However this test results in this error for me: "CoinFlip::rawFulfillRandomWords(1, [2])
│   │   └─ ← panic: array out-of-bounds access (0x32)". the rawFulfillRandomWords method can be found at:"https://github.com/smartcontractkit/chainlink-brownie-contracts/blob/c6d0ca512f1b09d93bc81415d246dbee7e5c6894/contracts/src/v0.8/VRFConsumerBaseV2.sol". I have no idea why I get this error and I've tried to change the length of the words I am passing as a parameter to 2 but I get an InvalidRandomWords error as I only request 1 random word in the contract. I would appreciate any help to fix this or maybe an alternative to test this functionality. My repo can be found here:https://github.com/edsardgrisel/foundry-coin-flip

```
function testFulfillRandomWordsHouseWin()
        public
        contractFunded
        usersSignedUp
    {
        uint256 startingTimeStamp = coinFlip.getLastTimeStamp();
        vm.prank(PLAYER1);
        coinFlip.bet{value: minBet}();
        vm.prank(PLAYER2);
        coinFlip.bet{value: minBet}();
        vm.warp(block.timestamp + interval + 1);
        vm.roll(block.number + 1);

        uint256 contractStartingBalance = address(coinFlip).balance;

        vm.recordLogs();
        coinFlip.performUpkeep(""); // emits requestId
        Vm.Log[] memory entries = vm.getRecordedLogs();
        bytes32 requestId = entries[1].topics[1]; // get the requestId from the logs

        uint256[] memory evenRandomWord = new uint256[](1);
        evenRandomWord[0] = 2;

        VRFCoordinatorV2Mock(vrfCoordinator).fulfillRandomWordsWithOverride(
            uint256(requestId),
            address(coinFlip),
            evenRandomWord
        );
        uint256 contractEndingBalance = address(coinFlip).balance;

        // Assert
        address[] memory recentWinners = coinFlip.getRecentWinners();
        CoinFlip.CoinFlipState coinFlipState = coinFlip.getCoinFlipState();
        uint256 endingTimeStamp = coinFlip.getLastTimeStamp();

        assertEq(recentWinners[0], coinFlip.getOwner());
        assertEq(recentWinners.length, 1);
        assert(uint256(coinFlipState) == 0);
        assertEq(contractStartingBalance, contractEndingBalance);
        assert(endingTimeStamp > startingTimeStamp);
        assertEq(address(PLAYER1).balance, STARTING_USER_BALANCE - minBet);
        assertEq(address(PLAYER2).balance, STARTING_USER_BALANCE - minBet);
    }
```

```
function fulfillRandomWords(
        uint256,
        uint256[] memory randomWords
    ) internal override {
        bool houseWin = randomWords[0] % 2 == 0;
        address payable[] memory winners;
        if (houseWin) {
            winners[0] = payable(address(this));
        } else {
            winners = s_betters;
        }
        s_recentWinners = winners;
        s_coinFlipState = CoinFlipState.OPEN;

        s_betters = new address payable[](0);
        s_lastTimeStamp = block.timestamp;

        //if house won, skip payout
        if (!houseWin) {
            //if house lost, payout to betters
            for (uint256 i = 0; i < s_recentWinners.length; i++) {
                //mapping(address => uint256) private s_addressToAmountBet;
                address winner = s_recentWinners[i];
                uint256 amountBet = s_addressToAmountBet[winner];
                (bool success, ) = winner.call{value: 2 * amountBet}("");
                if (!success) {
                    revert CoinFlip__TransferFailed();
                }
            }
        }
        emit WinnerPicked(winners);
    }
```